# Using Excel VBA to individually color y-axis lables

Tags: excel, vba, colors, axis, excel-charts

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of individual y-axis labels programmatically for a bar chart. Here's what the chart currently looks like:

[image: Current Chart Image]

Here's how I'd *like* it to look. (The colors on the "RX 5700 XT" lines are in red -- this is via a hasty PhotoShop hack, so this isn't set in stone, just an example of where I'm headed).

[image: Modified chart image]

The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to programmatically get at the individual text labels. The actual text isn't necessarily hard-coded, but based on matching some pattern I want to change the text colors -- a secondary coding of data, if you will.

Background: This is for my charts at Tom's Hardware, for GPU reviews specifically. In this case, I have all GPUs tested with one CPU colored one way (lighter grey and red), and all GPUs tested with a different CPU colored a different way (darker grey and red). However, I also want to potentially differentiate between AMD and Nvidia GPUs -- so highlight the AMD GPUs in Dark Red text as an example.

There are about 60 charts total, so manually changing colors on each chart after generation would be extremely inefficient. I could just use different bar chart colors, but that also gets messy. Theoretically, I want to get at myChart.Axes(xlCategory).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange ... but TextFrame2 is a read-only property. I recorded a macro where I changed the axis font color, but even that macro fails to play back properly. :\

Answer (score 0):

The axis labels on a chart cannot be colored individually. The axis font color applies to all text in the axis. Individual axis labels cannot be formatted differently. Not in the GUI and not with VBA.

Side note: You may want to review your color choices for the charts. The black/red/white in such close proximity is very hard on the eyes and causes eye strain and flimmer for some people.

Comment: There's no way to go through the TextFrame2.TextRange properties to control this? It seems like you could potentially set font stuff on a per-character basis through Chart.Axes(xlCategory).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters ... but how to actually do this is unclear to me. Or maybe it *is* impossible. I'm probably just going to change the chart coloring scheme and forget about the labels.